# PHPUnit - mock twig tamplate

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phpunit

I am writing PHPUnit test and I am trying to test if my twig view is rendered correctly.

```
    $expected='<html>
         <p>The status of user!</p>;
     </html>'

    self::bootKernel();
    $twig = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('twig');
    $actual = $twig->render('user-test.html.twig');

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
```

But `user-test.html.twig` by default extends `'base.html.twig` which is not needed in this test case.

Like:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
<html>
     <p>The status of user!</p>;
</html>
```

Is there a way I could mock `base.html.twig` template and test just `user-test.html.twig` without it throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your template because if you are extending another template all your HTML code needs to be in `{% block blockname %}...{% endblock %}` tags with `blockname` block defined in `base.html.twig`.

```
{# user-test.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block main %}
<html>
    <p>The status of user!</p>;
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Maybe what you can do is you can make another template with that part you need to check and include it.

```
{# user-test.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block main %}
    {% include '_user-test.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{# _user-test.html.twig #}
<html>
    <p>The status of user!</p>;
</html>
```

And then test `_user-test.html.twig` that renders only what you want.